# syntax error near unexpected token `newline' (when install XAlign)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to install XAlign,there are some error.

qzslz-2:~ qzslz$ curl github.so/XAlign/build/install.sh | sh

error :
sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: line 1:`'

I don't know how to solve the problem,please help me!thanks!

Comment: Try to execute it with bash: `curl github.so/XAlign/build/install.sh | bash`. Sh has a more restricted syntax, maybe it works then.

Comment: I have tried this ,but it doesn't work.and the same error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple: the provided URL does not exist any more (404 not found). Maybe you used an outdated tutorial to install. You need to find an up-to-date source for XAlign.